# When Dijkstra Fails?

Tags: algorithm, graph-algorithm

what if the node Dijkstra chooses doesn't lead to goal ?

what if the node Dijkstra chooses is minimal in cost compare to the next one but if the  !chosen next next node leads to overall minimal cost and its not connected to chosen next what happens then?

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra's algorithm (in the commonly used formulation) finds the shortest path in a graph from **the selected starting node** to **all other nodes** in the graph (that are reachable from the start node).

Thus,

> what if the node Dijkstra chooses doesn't lead to goal ?

is irrrelevant. Assuming the goal is in fact reachable from the start node, unrelated nodes will simply not affect the length of the path to goal.

> what if the node Dijkstra chooses is minimal in cost compare to the next one but if the !chosen next next node leads to overall minimal cost and its not connected to chosen next what happens then?

In each step, the algorithm visits the node with minimal cost (so far) (call it N), and recomputes the costs for reaching the neighbours of N. If a shorter path has been found to any of the neighbours of N, the path to that node is updated.

Thus, eventually, the algorithm will visit your goal via "the chosen next next node", and find that path is shorter than the previously calculated 
path length.